# Every link except home directes to 'Not found' page?

Tags: 8

I have created site directly on the shared host server by downloading fresh Drupal 8. Every think went Ok with installation and site installed properly. But whenever I click on any link of admin bar or my-accont/logout it directs me to `Not Found` page.

*For example I clicked on `Extend` from admin menu and following message did appear.*

> [image]

*Not found message*

> [image]

Any idea why this is happening and how to correct that. Very thanks.

Comment: Check https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/clean-urls-in-drupal-8/fix-drupal-8-clean-urls-problems

Comment: @4k4 Thanks for the link, it is very useful and target the issue, appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing (or having a malformed) htaccess file.

You can download a .htaccess file directly from drupal.org with the following link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drupal/drupal/8.2.x/.htaccess

If you want an htaccess file for a different disk version then you can change the version number in the above link.

Comment: Yes, you seems right, it is issue with .htaccess. I manage to see that file in my cPanel, but it is empty. I am not gettign why. Even I have installed fresh D8 directly on server and  have selected standard installation process. Hence there is least chance to missing something. I have already in talk with host, but could you let me know, what shall I put in that file or from where or it totally depends on host? Very thanks

Comment: Updated answer with the recommended htaccess file.

Comment: Hi, Eyal, I copied the code at my .htaccess, Now URLs are working perfectly as expected. Since it is somewhat hard to understand those codes on that link, except some comment which are clear to understand. I am going ahead with this, Just want to make sure as you might have used this, Should I be worried about some security issue if I am using this code or there is no such concern, very appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: The htaccess file above is from drupal.org and should be secure enough.

Answer (score 0):

As Eyal said, you have a problem with your .htaccess file. For further instructions, you may follow my blog post if you wish: https://masky-the-tech-nerd.blogspot.com/2016/12/how-to-install-drupal-on-ubuntu-1610.html